# How to set angular dropdown value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a dropdown like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="docPropIdentityModel.Status" class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- None --</option>
  <option value="1">Active</option>
  <option value="0">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to set its value to a specific option as follows:

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel.Status = 1;
```

I was expecting to set its value to 1, so that Active is shown as the dropdown option. But its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your option's value type is string.

In order to make it selected, you have to provide a string type data.

try like this

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel.Status="1";
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7xps3300/)**</kbd>

Comment: I thought it for a while then tried to set the value as int like <option value=1> which not worked as expected! Thanks.

Comment: tumar uchit hbe [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) use kora . esob kaj ngOptions handle kore dibe @Badhon

Comment: Ok, I will. asole ei dropdown gula always 2 ta value hold korbe, tai vabci inline diye dei. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In angularJS you want to binding select control than use dynamic populate select control. You are using static binding so this way you can`t able to select dynamic

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel.Status = [{Id:'1',Name:'Active'},{Id:'2',Name:'Inactive'}]

<select data-ng-model="docPropIdentityModel.Status" name="statuss"
        ng-options="status.Name for status in docPropIdentityModel.Status track by status.Id" required>
</select>
```